# Making Public API Calls with a simple API Key - Youtube Analytics API

Tags: php, api, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to make public call on the Youtube analytics api using a simple key. This is my PHP code:

```
<?
set_include_path('YoutubeAPI/src/Google');
require_once 'autoload.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
$client->setDeveloperKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

$resp = $youtube->reports->query('channel==UCww2zZWg4Cf5xcRKG-ThmXQ','2014-09-01','2014-09-05','views');
?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
[03-Jul-2015 11:29:26 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com//youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUCww2zZWg4Cf5xcRKG-ThmXQ&start-date=2014-09-01&end-date=2014-09-05&metrics=views&key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: (401) Login Required' in /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110
Stack trace:
#0 /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Http/REST.php(62): Google_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Google_Http_Request), Object(Google_Client))
#1 [internal function]: Google_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google_Http_Request))
#2 /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Task/Runner.php(174): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Http/REST.php(46): Google_Task_Runner->run()
#4 /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Client.php(593): Google_Http_REST::execute(Object(Google_Client), Object(Google in /home/optimaje/public_html/statstn/YoutubeAPI/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 110
```

I'm looking for the solution since a week and I'm still lost. Where's the error? Can someone give me a working sample code?

PS: I don't want to use Oauth2 login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing Google APIs using a public API key is quit simlar to using Oauth2.  Remember this will only work on calls that don't require authentication, if you need to be authenticated you need to use Oauth2 as the YouTube API does not support service account authentication.

Code ripped from [Simple-query.php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-query.php)

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$apiKey = "<YOUR_API_KEY>"; // Change this line.
// Warn if the API key isn't changed.
if (strpos($apiKey, "<") !== false) {
  echo missingApiKeyWarning();
  exit;
}
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);
```